# Final Cut Pro X & Davinci Resolve workflow

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, workflow, color-grading, davinci-resolve

I'd like to grade a Final Cut Pro X project with Davinci Resolve. Unfortunately my Final Cut experience is very limited and I don't understand how to get a consolidated project, linked to the **original footage files** in order to create a clean xml file for Davinci Resolve.

When I try to consolidate a project (*File > Consolidate*), Final Cut creates additional, encoded and conformed files with a weird naming scheme - unfortunately this is not what I expect.

Is there a way to keep the source footage links and create a 'clean edit' which is assembled from the source material instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do:

1. Duplicate the project for a backup.
2. "Collapse" the timeline from the bottom up:  Lasso all of the clips
   immediately above the primary storyline (to make a Premiere
   analogy, if the primary storyline is V1, then select all of the
   clips on V2), right click, and select "overwrite to primary
   storyline."
3. Repeat step 2 until there are no clips above the primary storyline.
4. File->Export XML
5. Import this xml file into Resolve
6. Color clips
7. Render individual source files
8. Replace FCPX clips with new ones

I don't have my DaVinci Dongle on me, or I'd elaborate on that side.